# Which variable stores the value of the document's margins?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to create a header. I would like to position the information on the right or left margin. But I do not know which command stores the margin dimension correctly. The `\leftmargin` command is not working the way I expected. I tried to calculate `\paperwidth` less `\textwidth`, but it also does not work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[left=5cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}{}}   
\fancyhead[LO]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[xshift=-\leftmargin, inner sep=0pt] (a) {aaaaVaaaa}; 
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The amount of the left margin is 1in+`\oddsidemargin` on odd numbered pages and 1in+`\evensidemargin` on even numbered pages.

Comment: You might want to look at the `layouts` package (`> texdoc layouts`) which shows many of LaTeX's layout parameters, such as page margins, and their current values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance of left side of the text block from the inner side of the paper is

```
1in + \hoffset + \oddsidemargin
```

on odd numbered pages and

```
1in + \hoffset + \evensidemargin
```

As you're using the `book` class (for which `twoside` is default), the two parameters are usually different.

Under normal circumstances, `\hoffset` is zero. However, it might be modified to comply with some printing device that has different ideas about where to place things on the paper, so it's better to keep it in the computation.

The reason for `1in` (one inch) is historical and has to do with the standard reference point of TeX (not the best decision, in my opinion).